# Wix change exe installer icon

Tags: c#, wix

Well, I wrote an add-on to excel and created a msi installer for it using wix toolset. The problem is that I would like to change the installer icon, but from what I read msi installer icons can not be changed and I wanted to ask you whether it is possible to change the installer from msi to some other (eg on exe) and then change the installer icon?

[Update]

I've already change msi file to exe using wix bootstrap, but still i don't know how could i change this icon.

Thanks for all the tips / help.

**This problem is not duplicate of [Change exe icon based on define C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976691/change-exe-icon-based-on-define-c-sharp)**

my problem is not a duplicate of the post that was indicated, because it is a wix project and the given solution is for wpf, winforms projects.

In my project, there is no csproj file, only wixproj, which does not even have the `<ApplicationIcon>` tag.

Project properties are also different because there is no context in the build tab.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change exe icon based on define C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976691/change-exe-icon-based-on-define-c-sharp)

Comment: this is not a solution for my issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot change the icon displayed by Windows for *.msi file.

For bundle exe's use

```
<Bundle ... IconSourceFile='path\to\product.ico'>
```

This will also change the icon in the "Add/Remove Programs" (which is probably good).